# How to (automatically) inherit settings/tasks from an sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have an sbt plugin defining tasks that I would like to have available in a Play project, or another sbt project in general. While it might not be best practice, I'd prefer to have these tasks automatically available in the Play project, so that all I need to do is add the sbt plugin via plugins.sbt. But before I can even get that far, I'm having trouble importing tasks at all.

If the plugin's build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "sbt-task-test"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

scalaBinaryVersion := "2.10"

organization := "com.example"

sbtPlugin := true

lazy val testTask = taskKey[Unit]("Run a test task.")

testTask := {
    println("Running test task..")
}
```

How can I make `testTask` available in another sbt project's build.sbt or Build.scala? I've tried following [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#example-plugin) example to no avail.

My end goal is to use tasks defined like in this [blog post](http://kailuowang.blogspot.com/2013/05/define-arbitrary-tasks-in-play-21.html), but I'd like to at least get some simpler examples working first. In this case, I'd be adding something like `registerTask("testTask", "com.example.tasks.Test", "Run a test task")` to build.sbt, however I have the same problem as above.

Comment: Did you follow one of the steps at the [bottom of the example page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#global-plugins-example) for making a plugin recognizable, and did you add it as a dependency to your project? `libraryDependencies += "com.example" ...`

Comment: I'm not looking to make a global plugin like in that link. I've added the plugin both in plugins.sbt and as a library depenency in Build.scala. `testTask` is still not a valid key in the project including the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should put your task definition in the *source* of the plugin, not the `build.sbt`. So try this:

- `build.sbt` of the plugin (it defines only how to *build* the plugin):

  ```
  name := "sbt-task-test"

  version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

  scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

  // scalaBinaryVersion := "2.10" // better not to play with this

  organization := "com.example"

  sbtPlugin := true
  ```
- `src/main/scala/MyPlugin.scala` (in the plugin project)

  ```
  import sbt._

  object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

      lazy val testTask = taskKey[Unit]("Run a test task.")

      override def settings = Seq(
          testTask := { println("Running test task..") }
      )

  }
  ```

Overriding settings helps to add the definition of this task to the project scope.
Now you should build and publish the plugin (locally for example) using `sbt publishLocal`.

Then in the project, where you want to use this plugin:

- `project/plugins.sbt` should contain:

  ```
  addSbtPlugin("com.example" % "sbt-task-test" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
  ```

This will add `testTask` key and definition to the scope automatically, so that you can do in the project's directory:

```
sbt testTask
```

and it will print `Running test task..`

Comment: One question. Might there be any adverse effects from overriding settings? i.e. causing things to break in unexpected ways?

Comment: Well, settings/tasks have dependencies between them, you can see it with `inspect testTask` in sbt. So that when you override some setting you see which other keys were affected.
You can try in sbt `set version := "42"` and you will see a line `The new value will be used by ....`, then you can use `last` for more information on it.